# SetPixel equivalent on mac?

Tags: c, macos, pixel

I'm currently writing a software renderer and after i got it to kind of work on windows I began thinking about porting it to Mac.

My Question therefore is: What's the equivalent to the Win32 GDI SetPixel function?
All I need to be able to do is plot a pixel at (x,y).

I'm new to mac development and the closest thing I found resembling an answer was to use an OpenGL Texture to which one would draw to. But that kind of defeats the point of having software rendering if i have to use OpenGL...

Is it even possible to plot single pixels in osx?

Comment: of course there will be some kind of canvas component for direct pixel drawing, you don't need OpenGL for 2D plots for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

Just use LibSDL (preferably version 2.0).

#### Long answer

You have to get your pixel data from system memory to graphics memory anyway.  One way to do that is with OpenGL.  You can think of OpenGL as a fancy API which lets you push data from system memory to graphics memory.  Since that's exactly what you want to do, it makes sense to use OpenGL.

> But that kind of defeats the point of having software rendering if i have to use OpenGL...

The graphics card is going to do the work of compositing your pixels on the screen whether you like it or not so you don't get any particular portability advantages by avoiding OpenGL.  Back in the 90s you could just get a pointer to the framebuffer and push pixels there, but those days are gone.

LibSDL is nice because it gives you an API which lets you push pixels to a buffer, and then LibSDL takes care of putting the buffer on screen.

`SetPixel()` is horribly slow anyway, so you should be using LibSDL on Windows too.

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking for this info! I want to dig deeper into game engines and how games where made in the 90s (Quake etc.). I want to start by writing a small basic software renderer and was wondering, if its even possible to bypass the GPU nowadays. I already started using GLFW and then SDL (also for cross platform support) and now I know it's the right choice :). For anyone who's interested in this topic, make sure to check out https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer